# Passing Textarea field through Ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, textarea

I'm sending a contact form through Ajax, all values are sending and processing fine but for some reason the message content is not passing from the textarea field, I've tried `var note = $("textarea#note").text();` and `var note = $("textarea#note").val();` I've also tried both with `$("$note")` but still to no avail. I'm sure the value of the text area is being picked up but it's just not passing in the string.

Here's my code:

```
$('#formsend').click(function(){

var detail = $("input#subject").val();
var note = $("textarea#note").text();

var dataString = $('form').serialize();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "processmail.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Message Submitted.</h2>")
    .append("<p>Thank you for contacting me, I will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500);
  }
});
return false;

}); //end form ajax
```

but I have tried passing the data as:

```
data:{
      'detail': detail
      'note': note
      }
```

Both methods seem to work with all fields except they do not pass the value of the text area through to my php file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Simply use `$("#note").val()` - this should work if you have textarea like `<textarea id="note">..</textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,you can get content through this `$("$note")`,you should use  `$("#note")`

```
$('#formsend').click(function(){

var detail = $("input#subject").val();
var note = $("#note").text();

var dataString = $('form').serialize();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "processmail.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Message Submitted.</h2>")
    .append("<p>Thank you for contacting me, I will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500);
  }
});
return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use $("#note").val() - this should work if you have textarea with the id `note`

```
<textarea id="note">..</textarea>
```

js:

```
$('#formsend').click(function(){


var detail = $("input#subject").val();
var note = $("#note").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "processmail.php",
  data: {detail: detail, note: note},
  success: function() {
    $('#form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Message Submitted.</h2>")
    .append("<p>Thank you for contacting me, I will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500);
  }
});
return false;

});
```